# Is trace functional strongly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Trace functional is defined on space of trace class operators  as $Tr:B_1(\mathcal H)\to \mathbb C$ $$Tr(A)=\sum_{\alpha\in I}<Ae_\alpha,e_\alpha>$$ where $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilber space $\mathcal H$.  I was wondering if this functional is continuous with respect to the strong topology on $B_1(\mathcal H)$ inherited from $B(\mathcal H)$?

Comment: $(A,B)=Tr(B^* A)$ is an inner product (bilinear form with $(A,A) > 0$) and the trace norm is $\|A\|_{Tr} = \sqrt{(A,A)}$, that $\|A\|_{Tr} < \infty$ means $\|A e_n\|_H\in \ell^2$ while $Tr(A)$ is bounded by the $\ell^1$ norm of $\|Ae_n\|_H$ thus it is obvious $Tr$ isn't bounded/continuous wrt the trace norm (concretely $Ax = \sum_n  <x,e_n>n^{-2/3} e_n$ then $Tr(A) = \infty,\|A\|_{Tr} <\infty$)

Comment: @reuns What you defined as $\|A\|_\text{tr}$ is not the trace-norm but the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. In fact, $$\|A\|_\text{tr}=\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^*A)}\neq \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^*A)}=\|A\|_\text{HS}\,.$$As one readily verifies, $|\operatorname{tr}(A)|\leq\|A\|_\text{tr}$ for all $A\in\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ so $\operatorname{tr}$ is trace norm-continuous---which was not even the question.

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde Right the orthonormal basis independent version of the $\ell^1$ norm is $tr ( (A^*A)^{1/2})$ (for which $Tr$ is bounded) I wanted to show the OP it takes 2 lines to define it and check its properties. I'm quite sure it was the question (because as it is it doesn't make any sense)

Comment: @reuns The question makes sense if one reasonably assumes that OP talks about either (a) the trace class equipped with the operator norm (instead of the usual trace norm) or (b) the weak topology on (the Banach space) $\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$, i.e. on functionals $X\mapsto tr(XB)$ for some $B\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ as those precisely form the dual space $(\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H))′$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: there exist positive numbers $a_{nk}$ such that $\sum_k (a_{nk})^{2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but $\sum_k a_{nk}$ does not tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. On $\ell^{2}$ define $T_n(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  a_{nk} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$ where $(e_n)$ is the usual orthonormal basis. Then trace of $T_n$ (which is $\sum_k a_{nk}$) does not tend to $0$ but $\|T_n\| \to 0$.

Comment: Not sure how this is an answer, as OP's question does not contain the Hilbert-Schmidt norm in any way?

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde I am not talking about Hilbert Schmidt norm. I am saying that the operator norm of $T_n$ tends to $0$ but trace of $T_n$ does not tend to $0$. OP is clearly talking about operator norm on the class of trace class operators.

Comment: I agree that OP's question is ambiguous because he could either refer to the operator norm ("[norm] topology on $\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ inherited from $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$) or the weak topology on $\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ (inherited from $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\simeq (\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H))'$ by means of $\operatorname{tr}(B(\cdot))$). The former, however, does not make too much sense as $(\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H),\|\cdot\|)$ is not even closed within $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$.

Comment: (2/2) Either way, the operator norm of your $T_n$ (because diagonal) is $\max_{k\in\mathbb N} a_{nk}$, whereas $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N} (a_{nk})^2$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $T_n$, hence my original comment. Of course your counter-example can be easily modified, e.g., by choosing $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \langle e_k,\cdot\rangle e_k$ so $\operatorname{tr}(T_n)=1$ for all $n$ but $\|T_n\|=\frac1n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: $\|T_nx\|^{2}=\sum_k |a_{nk}|^{2} | \langle x, e_k \rangle|^{2} \leq \|x \|^{2} \sum_k |a_{nk}|^{2}$, so $\|T_n\|^{2} \leq  \sum_k |a_{nk}|^{2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. @FrederikvomEnde

Comment: I guess one can use the general inequality $\|\cdot\|\leq\|\cdot\|_\text{HS}$ to tackle this problem, although I don't see the need to do that (given the counter-example I propsed above is just as simple). But that approach of course works as well.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There Is no ambiguity. I just asked if the $tr$ function is continuous on the subsapce $B_1(\mathcal H)$ with the subspace topology inherited from strong topology of $B(\mathcal H)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous because there is no such thing as "*strong* topology on $\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ inherited from $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$".
If you mean $\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ together with the operator norm $\|\cdot\|$ (which turns $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ into a Banach space) then the answer to your question is negative (cf. Kavi's answer and the respective comments).

If you mean (which given your wording makes more sense to me) the **weak topology on** the Banach space $\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$, i.e.
$$
A_i\overset{i\to\infty}\to 0\text{ weakly if }|\operatorname{tr}(A_iB)|\overset{i\to\infty}\to 0\text{ for all }B\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H) .
$$
Here one uses that the dual space $(\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H))'\simeq\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ contains precisely the functionals $A\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(AB)$ for some $B\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$. Note that the strong topology (on spaces of operators on $\mathcal H$) is something very different.

For the question itself, the trace is trivially weakly continuous because it is obviously is of trace-form. Indeed, if $A_i\to 0$ weakly, then choosing $B=\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal H}$ in the above definition shows $|\operatorname{tr}(A_i)|\to 0$.